# Android FaceRecognition App -- Issues with CvOpenFileStorage()

Tags: android, face-recognition, javacv

I'm working on a face-recognition application on Android using JavaCV.  I'm currently having issues accessing a facedata.xml file which will contain the data from the trained images. This is my code:

```
CvFileStorage fileStorage;

fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage("/sdcard/external_sd/facedata.xml", null,         CV_STORAGE_WRITE, null); 

cvOpenFileStorage returns null
```

I'm not sure if it is an issue with JavaCV or what i'm doing wrong. It should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Make sure path of the file you have provided is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this, seemingly to do the exact same thing, my code is:

```
fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage("/sdcard/FaceDB/facedata.xml", // filename
            null, // memstorage
            CV_STORAGE_WRITE, // flags
            null); // encoding
```

Just from looking at the file path I would say that is most likely wrong as it looks strange to have a folder called external_sd in your sd card.
If not it could be another problem, I found a lot of weird problems that were hard to trouble shoot with JavaCV

Answer (score 0):

It seams, cvOpenFileStorage can not allocate memory for facedata.xml.
When I create facedata.xml with large size (20meg), manualy, it worke and can write to facedata.xml file.
So, just copy a facedata.xml file with large size in your directory ("/sdcard/external_sd/").